# Single index in Alter table wont get added if its part of a multi column index

Tags: mysql, indexing, alter-table

I have this inside a stored procedure so far:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
        AND TABLE_NAME= 'food'  AND (INDEX_NAME='ix_meat' OR COLUMN_NAME='meat')
    )
THEN
    CREATE INDEX ix_meat ON food (meat);
END IF; 


IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
        AND TABLE_NAME= 'food'  AND (INDEX_NAME='ix_greens' OR COLUMN_NAME='greens')
    )
THEN
    CREATE INDEX ix_greens ON food(greens);
END IF;
```

Rest of the columns in food besides primary are:

> fruits,  portion,  gender,  weight

I want to add only a single index if there is no single index on these columns or if either of them are part of a multi column index but on the right side like (gender, greens). To be sure a single column index doesn’t already exist, I'd need to include a row count check on that column. How do I modify this script to do that?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Your query doesn't distinguish single column and multi column indexes. It just checks whether the column is in any index.

Comment: Note that it you want queries that just test `greens` to use the index, it has to be the first column in an index. So you should check `seq_in_index = 1`.

Comment: Yeah that is my question on how to distinguish single column and multi column indexes, right now I am only checking for any. I tried couple things off stack and they did not work.

Comment: Why do you want to add the index if there's already a single-column index?

Comment: It definitely wont allow that. I want to add only a single index if there is no single index on that column or if the column is part of a multi column index but is on the right side like (gender, greens)

Comment: Reminds me of a gardener with a noisy leaf blower chasing a single leaf that does not want to go where he wants it.  I want to tell him _Just do it manually._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `seq_in_index` column to tell where the column is in an index. You want to add the index unless it's the first column in an index.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
        AND TABLE_NAME= 'food'  AND (INDEX_NAME='ix_meat' OR (COLUMN_NAME='meat' AND SEQ_IN_INDEX = 1))
    )
THEN
    CREATE INDEX ix_meat ON food (meat);
END IF; 


IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
        AND TABLE_NAME= 'food'  AND (INDEX_NAME='ix_greens' OR (COLUMN_NAME='greens' AND SEQ_IN_INDEX = 1))
    )
THEN
    CREATE INDEX ix_greens ON food(greens);
END IF;
```